# method that returns array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I'm starting out with C# and I created a method to add values to an array from a text stream and return the array as follows:

```
    private static string[] getLines(StreamReader myStream)
    {
        string[] lines;
        while (!myStream.EndOfStream)
        {
           lines = new string[] { myStream.ReadLine() };
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

I'm getting a **use of unassigned variable 'lines'** in the return parameter.

Comment: set string[] lines= null at the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of the unintialized parameter `lines` being used. If you want to read the whole file, instead of reading lines in iteration use `ReadToEnd()`. It will help in avoiding the `while` loop.

```
  private static string[] getLines(StreamReader myStream)
  {
      string[] lines = null;
      if(myStream != null)
      {
          lines = myStream.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
      }
      return lines;
  }
```

You can also use `.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);` to get the array which avoids the `\n` magic string that will not work cross platform.

Comment: copied wrong code earlier. you do not need to run while loop to get all lines. instead use ReadToEnd to get the whole file n split it with new line character to get the array

Comment: This is a useful approach for small files but may choke on large files - `ReadToEnd()` reads the entire file into memory

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to initialize the variable 'lines', because the compiler recognizes the possibility that your loop will contain zero elements, and you cannot return an uninitialized variable as the value for a method. But that is the least of your problems.
You are not adding to the array, in fact, you cannot increase the capacity of an array once it has been initialised. 
You'll see that when this code runs, you will simply get an array of length 1 that only contains the last element of the text. This is because you are constantly reinitializing your array. (Notice the word 'new'?)

Your method would be better served with a list:

```
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while (!myStream.EndOfStream)
    {
       lines.Add(myStream.ReadLine());
    }

    return lines.ToArray();
```

Comment: Of course he can also consider changing the return type of the method to `List<string>` and then `return lines;` directly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private static string[] getLines(StreamReader myStream)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while (!myStream.EndOfStream)
    {
       lines.Add(myStream.ReadLine());
    }
    return lines.ToArray();
}
```